# Элементы типа Button InputText и другие View выводятся в эмуляторе без стилей

Tags: android-studio, xml, kotlin, android-data-binding

В моем проекте как-то странно работает разметка. PS Я пробовал ребилдить и скидывать кэш, но это не помогло. Создаю новое пустое активити вношу такие же данные и все работает.
Манифест стоковый. В градле точно также.
Работаю в Android Studio на kotlin и xml. Пытаюсь сделать интерфейс, пока никаких фремворков не использую чистый AS. Проблема с xml версткой и её выводом в эмуляторе

Как должно:
[image: Как должно]

Как получается в ходе эмуляции:
[image: Как получается в эмуляторе]

Comment: Что это вообще такое? Добавьте подробностей: язык, технология, фреймворк.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Работаю в Android Studio. Пытаюсь сделать интерфейс, пока никаких фремворков не использую чистый AS. Проблема с xml версткой файла layout и её выводом в эмуляторе. Я делаю мне необходимый элемент, но окончательная версия при эмуляции выходит не та что должна.

Comment: Я не много понял в чем проблема, я использую data Binding в своем проекте и когда я включаю его и перехожу на дефолтное отображение setContentView(R.Id.layout), то все отображается как нужно. Но я создал новый проект и почему то байдинг там работает. В общем пока решил попробовать заченжить проекты

Comment: Ваш вопрос почти никто не видит! Люди подписываются на метки; система показывает им вопросы по меткам. Я подписан на xml, я увидел ваш вопрос. Смекаете? Добавьте метки, какой язык используется и прочее. Вон вы пишете: "создаю проект" - что это за проект, какого типа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать так то все ок

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

@Override
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Если же так то стили не подгружаются

```
    private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

@Override
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Все таки последовательность кода при инициализации присутствует